# Android: Why a simple layout test on Nexus One and Galaxy Nexus give different result?

Tags: android

I'm new in android.
I have create a simple example to test the scaling function of Android on Nexus One and Galaxy Nexus.

This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/sfondo"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.testlayout.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Using a particular background image with specific text positions, I have that the positions of text are correct in one device and not in the other.

This two phones are in the same layout category: normal.

Why do I get two different results?(also using dp)
how can I do to have the same result in both devices?
Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I suggest that you upload screenshots somewhere of what you are seeing and link to them from your question, as we have no good idea what "not in the other" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With dp you ensure the *physical size* of the Views and of the margins is the same on all devices.

That means if you use a background image that fills the whole screen, and you have devices with a different screen size, the locations on the image of the Views will be different for each device.

Small example:

Take a 10cm screen, 160 dp. Use a margin in dp that will physically result in a 1 cm margin (10% of the screen).

Now take a 20cm screen, 160dp. With the same margin in dp, pysically it will still be 1cm, but that is only 5% of the screen. But the physical size of the background will be double of the size it has on the 10cm screen, so the positioning will be off.

One solution for this problem would be to do the positioning in code, so you can scale the based on the available pixels of the screen, but generally I'd not recommend you to use such a background image that needs absolute positioning of Views on it.